# How to Use Impression Beacons to Read Server Call Data (Pixel)

Tags: php, pixel, bug-tracking

I need to get some sort of understanding on sending server to server information using pixels. We use validclick and they say their beacon must be sent to a 1x1 transparent image. From all the looking that I've done I cannot find a basic "how to" about receiving data using a 1x1 gif.

What I have right now is a .php file with my gif and then my script to read the query string from the URL and insert it into our database.

```
   <?php

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCNdjYAAAAAIAAeIhvDMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');


   $conversion = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $info = explode("&", $conversion);
    $variables = array('id' => '', 'ts' => '', 'slotid' => '', 'q' => '', 'u' => '', 'ty' => '', 'nq' => '', 'nr' => '');
    foreach ($info as $i) {
        $temp = explode("=", $i);
        $variables[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
    }

    // Connect to the database
    try {
        // Info to connect to the database
        $servername = "****";
        $dbusername = "****";
        $password = "****";
        $dbname = "****";

        // To connect to the database please
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') ' . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e;
    }

    $variables['ts'] = str_replace("%", " ", $variables['ts']);
    echo $variables['ts'];
    $insert = "INSERT INTO validclickimpressions (id, ts, slotid, q, u, ty, nq, nr) " . 
        "VALUES ('" . $variables['id'] . "', '" .
            $variables['ts'] . "', '" .
            $variables['slotid'] . "', '" .
            $variables['q'] . "', '" .
            $variables['u'] . "', '" .
            $variables['ty'] . "', '" .
            $variables['nq'] . "', '" .
            $variables['nr'] . "')";

    if(!$conn->query($insert)){
        die('There was an error running the query "' . $insert . '" [' . $conn->error . ']');
    }

    $conn -> close;
?>
```

I think I am just missing some fundemetal understanding about how these beacons work. validclick is supposed to send info to this URL with those variables appended to the end of the URL. So this works when I visit with a test URL (ex: http://www.mywebsite.com/beacon_url/impression_beacon.php?id=1234&ts=2018-01-12%14:44:30&slotid=1234&q=1234&u=1234&ty=1234&nq=1234&nr=1234), but doesn't seem to be inserting data into our table when we receive impressions.

---

EDIT: I believe my issue is that my php is in with my image. I think the page can only contain the image. However I have no idea how to receive the data from the beacon if I remove it from the page.

Comment: Hmmmm seems possible that your problem is more a problem of timing than a problem in your implementation (though, to be honest I didn't look closely). Conceptually if they are sending data to your page, and PHP is server side... so it is one of the first things to run, then their (most likely, javascript provided data) would run after the page is rendered (after your PHP code has run & finished). Maybe use js to connect to a PHP service that will accept the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this php code will help anyone trying to setup an impression beacon in the future. This code is for Inuvo.

```
/*
* YPA Impression BEACON END POINT
*/

// *** lowercase all param names ***
$_REQUEST = array_change_key_case($_REQUEST);

// Default impression args
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ?  $_REQUEST['id'] : null; //  = coresponding impression ID
$ts = isset($_REQUEST['ts']) ?  $_REQUEST['ts'] : null; //  = unix timestamp of impression
$slotid = isset($_REQUEST['slotid']) ?  $_REQUEST['slotid'] : null; //  = location in page
$q = isset($_REQUEST['q']) ?  $_REQUEST['q'] : null; // = keyword
$u = isset($_REQUEST['u']) ?  $_REQUEST['u'] : null; // = landing page url
$ty = isset($_REQUEST['ty']) ?  $_REQUEST['ty'] : null; // = affid
$nq = isset($_REQUEST['nq']) ?  $_REQUEST['nq'] : null; // = number of ads requested for that ad unit / slot (New)
$nr = isset($_REQUEST['nr']) ?  $_REQUEST['nr'] : null; // = number of ads returned for that ad unit / slot (New)


// Your custom args defined in your YPA code block
// serveBeacon:"x=1&y=2&z=3", //string of key value pairs you want to hit this end point.
$x = isset($_REQUEST['x']) ?  $_REQUEST['x'] : null;
$y = isset($_REQUEST['y']) ?  $_REQUEST['y'] : null;
$z = isset($_REQUEST['z']) ?  $_REQUEST['z'] : null;

// write to your storage/db here


// Return image 1x1 gif content
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
echo base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw==');
```